# MediaElement Query

Tags: c#, wpf, mediaelement

In my application I'm getting the video file as a byte[] from the database and my requirement is like to play that video file using WPF media Element. 
Just want to know what is the best and elegant way to do that.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this function for playing videos in wpf using media element ...

It was given best results and i had already use this one...

pls go through this link for More Information On [how to play video in wpf uisng media element](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/WPF_Media_Player.aspx)

```
 /// <summary>
/// Handles Drop Event for Media Items.
/// </summary>
private void Media_Drop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    string[] fileNames = e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop, true) 
        as string[];
    //keep a dictionary of added files
    foreach (string f in fileNames)
    {
        if (IsValidMediaItem(f))
            mediaItems.Add(f.Substring(f.LastIndexOf(@"\")+1),
    new MediaItem(@f,0));
    }

    //now add to the list
    foreach (MediaItem mi in mediaItems.Values)
        lstMediaItems.Items.Add(mi);

    // Mark the event as handled,
    // so the control's native Drop handler is not called.
    e.Handled = true;
}

/// <summary>
/// check to see if dragged items are valid
/// </summary>
/// <returns>true if filename is valid</returns>
private bool IsValidMediaItem(string filename)
{
    bool isValid = false;
    string fileExtesion = filename.Substring(filename.LastIndexOf("."));
    foreach (string s in MediaItem.allowableMediaTypes)
    {
        if (s.Equals(fileExtesion, 
    StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
            isValid = true;
    }
    return isValid;
}
```

I hope it will helps you...

Comment: Thanks for the answer but my question is different. I'm getting the byte array from the database and my question is like what I have to do to the byte[] so that I can play my video without any performance issue.  One solution is like to convert the byte[] to memory stream and play the video, but I think it is not the correct way to do this coz it is not recommended to load the whole video into the memory stream. So what is the best and elegant way to do this?